# How to fix duplicate symbols in xCode 4.5.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Reading the previous posts on StackOverflow on this topic I could not find the right solution.

I'm compiling my project and I get lots of duplicate symbol errors like:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XMPPXFacebookPlatformAuthentication in:
    /Users/mirzahat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chattar-ajtakwrcojkkiehegfaxjkhesaej/Build/Intermediates/Chattar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChatProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/XMPPXFacebookPlatformAuthentication.o
    /Users/mirzahat/Desktop/Apps/Externals/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(XMPPXFacebookPlatformAuthentication.o)
```

I found the DerivedData folder of the project where the linker is stopping and I delete the folder. However it gets created every time I compile the project in simulator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try Clean , then Build the project ?

Comment: yes thats the first I did

Comment: Check Build Phase. Did you include duplicated header files, or duplicated source files ?

Comment: compile sources have only .m files, not duplicated...hint: the duplicate error appears only when I add -ObjC to other linker flags (I have to because I need Admob ads) without the -ObjC my app works perfect

Comment: XMPPXFacebookPlatformAuthentication is in the framework. Make sure it in not added again in your project . and Derived data will be generated each time the build is performed. It will have all the product related info in it